# what contains file during overwriting content in php?

Tags: php, file, fwrite, overwrite

Assuming I want to overwrite a file with a big content.
What will the others get if they pull content of file during overwriting ? First content? Nothing?

Comment: You should write file to another temp file once it's written replace it with the previous one.

Comment: And if I don't ? What will the others get if they pull content of file during overwriting ?

Comment: They will possibly receive partial file.

Comment: It depends on far too many factors. The OS, the filesystem, how other applications are opening the file, etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek can you give me examples of behavior?

Comment: In general: expected the unexpected. So if you want specific guarantees, like atomicity of the whole content for example, you have to code explicitly for them, using locks (hugely depending on the OS and filesystems), or copying alongside (which should work everywhere but introduce race conditions).

Comment: This recent link I just got discusses at length your problem and the broad complexity of it: https://danluu.com/deconstruct-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing probably. I personally will tackle this situation with the method as such:

1. Upload file as 'temporary.php'
2. Delete the old file.
3. Rename newly uploaded temporary.php to the old file.

Process of renaming would have almost no latency, but if you want to be safe, probably you can have the viewer refresh the page once if the old file is missing.